# Can Not Read id on JSF Components

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, jsf

I have a little problem
I am trying to use MartkItUp JQuery rich text editor on JSF textarea component.
My form looks like this:

```
 <h:form id="comment">
    <h:inputTextarea id="commentBody" cols="10" rows="10" value="#{postComment.commentBody}" required="true" requiredMessage="Comment Body is reqguired" >
      <f:validateLength maximum="500" minimum="2" />
    </h:inputTextarea>
                <%-- more of the form... %-->
```

The problem is that on output it gives me the id for textarea like that

```
id="comment:commentBody"
```

When I try in JQuery to point to it nothing happens.

```
$('#comment:commentBody').markItUp(mySettings);
```

I had a plain textarea before, and there was no problem. Now, I have a lot of them.

How do I point to id in JQuery, thats looks like **comment:commentBody**

P.S: I know i can point to this text area by $('textarea').markItUp(mySettings); however i am looking for solution to point to specific text area by it's ID.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this, `$('#comment\\:commentBody')`, for JQuery version 1.1.3 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("textarea[id$='commentBody']").markItUp(mySettings);
```

this will select text area having ID **ending** with *commentBody*.

to select control with ID starting with particular string replace **$** with **^**

Comment: Got an error when was trying to use your method.
But either way, thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1):

You can read about JSF IDs [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/02/jsf-working-with-component-ids.html), but in this case you may also find the *h:form* [prependId](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/h/form.html) attribute useful.