# JQuery not applying on JSF Dynamic UI Component

Tags: jquery, jsf

I have a problem with JQuery applying on JSF datatable.

I have my code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('<b>#example</b>').dataTable( {
                    "aoColumns": [
                        { "asSorting": [ "asc" ] },
                        { "asSorting": [ "asc" ] },
                        { "asSorting": [ "desc", "asc", "asc" ] },
                        { "asSorting": [ "desc" ] },
                        { "asSorting": [ "asc" ] },
                        { "asSorting": [ "asc" ] }
                    ]
                } );
            } );
        </script>
```

XHTML

```
<h:dataTable id="example" name="example" value="#{notificationBean.notificationList}" var="item"
                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
                styleClass="display"
                rowClasses="gradeC"
                style="background-image: url('../images/ClientCare_Menu_Gradient.jpg'); background-repeat: repeat-x;">
```

When it renders:

```
<table id="searchform:example" class="display" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background-image: url('../images/ClientCare_Menu_Gradient.jpg'); background-repeat: repeat-x;">
```

Now my problem is The CSS which has to apply for the datatable is not getting applied.

I tried different notations still it didnt work
in Jquery i tried:

${'#searchform:example'},   ${'#searchform.example'}
In these cases the Hover action on the containing table itself will not work to display the datatable.

${'searchform#example'},   ${'#example'}
In these cases the hover action works and datatable is rendered but CSS is not applying

Can anyone help in this ??

Thanks in advance 
Deepak

Comment: What's that `<b></b>` doing there in the jQuery selector?

Comment: Have a look to this related [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973496/cannot-pickup-id-with-jquery-for-the-jsf-textarea)

Comment: <b></b>  is just a formating...  i just tried to make it bold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the client ID of the generated HTML `<table>` element, not by the component ID of the JSF `<h:dataTable>` component. The HTML ID is in your particular case `searchform:example`. Since `:` is an illegal character in CSS selectors, you need to escape it:

```
$("#searchform\\:example")
```

or use the attribute selector instead:

```
$("[id='searchform:example']")
```

Easier would be to give the `<h:dataTable>` a style class instead.

```
<h:dataTable styleClass="example">
```

In your particular case, you already have one

```
<h:dataTable styleClass="display">
```

So you can also just use

```
$(".display")
```

Comment: Wow Wow the first option did work like a charm...  

Thanks a lot Balu...  :) :)